# AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'Y'

Tags: python, class, dictionary

This is the error I'm getting

AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute '_Student__student'

I clearly have my mutator in class Student:

```
self.__work = work
def set__work(self,work):
   self.__work = work 

def get_work(self):
   return self.__work

def add(students_info):
name = input("Enter the student name:")
ID = input("Enter student's ID:")
GPA= input("Enter GPA:")
grade = input("Enter student's expected grade:")
work = input("Does the student work part time or full time?")
students=student.Student(name, ID, GPA, grade, work)
if ID not in students_info:
    students_info[ID] = students
    print(students_info[ID])
else:
    print("Entry already existed")
```

I've been staring at this for hours but I still don't understand why I'm getting this code. Clearly, I init and return and set work to class 'Student' Any ideas? Help! Thanks

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444576/python-method-name-with-double-underscore-is-overridden

Comment: don't use getters setters without a good reason