# AttributeError: object has no attribute in class python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

When this class is called, I get  AttributeError: 'FixedLayout' object has no attribute '__fit_to_window'.
I have tried to figure out why this is, but I couldn't find anything that helped.
I saw this exact same code working on a system running python 2.7, could that be the issue here? I really don't know what else to say here, but if you have any questions please ask and If I can I will answer.

```
        from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
        from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
        from kivy.core.window import Window

        class FixedLayout(ScatterLayout):

            screensize = ObjectProperty((1920, 1080))

            def __init__(self, **kw):
                kw['size'] = (Window.width, Window.height)
                kw['size_hint'] = (None, None)
                kw['do_scale'] = False
                kw['do_translation'] = False
                kw['do_rotation'] = False
                super(FixedLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
                self.__fit_to_window()
                Window.bind(system_size=self.__fit_to_window)
                self.screensize = ObjectProperty((1920, 1080))

            def __fit_to_window(self, *args):
                screen_ratio = self.screensize[0]/float(self.screensize[1])
                window_ratio = Window.width/float(Window.height)
                if screen_ratio > window_ratio:
                    self.scale = Window.width/float(self.screensize[0])
                else:
                    self.scale = Window.height/float(self.screensize[1])
                print('self.scale ', self.scale)
                print('screen_ratio, window_ratio', screen_ratio, window_ratio)
                print('screensize', self.screensize)
                print('window size', Window.width, Window.height)
```

Output:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
        [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
        [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
        [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
        [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.43'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 980 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
        [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
        self.scale  0.4166666666666572
        screen_ratio, window_ratio 1.7777777777777777 1.3333333333333333
        screensize (1920, 1080)
        window size 800 600
        [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
        self.scale  0.4166666666666572
        screen_ratio, window_ratio 1.7777777777777777 1.3333333333333333
        screensize (1920, 1080)
        window size 800 600
         Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "c:/Users/DWL/Documents/Python_Projects/Kivy/TestMancala/MancalaTest.py", line 23, in <module>
             presentation = Builder.load_file('mancala.kv')
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
             return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 382, in load_string
             self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 566, in _apply_rule
             self.apply(child)
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 451, in apply
             self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 564, in _apply_rule
             child = cls(__no_builder=True)
           File "c:\Users\DWL\Documents\Python_Projects\Kivy\TestMancala\fixedlayout.py", line 17, in __init__
             Window.bind(system_size=self.__fit_to_window)
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 439, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy\_event.c:6558)
           File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 951, in kivy._event.EventObservers.bind (kivy\_event.c:11000)
           File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\weakmethod.py", line 47, in __call__
             return getattr(self.proxy, self.method_name)
         AttributeError: 'FixedLayout' object has no attribute '__fit_to_window'
```

Comment: `__fit_to_window` is a private method, because of those two underscores. The whole point of private methods is that Python mangles the name so code outside of your class, like that code in `kivy.weakmethod`, can't access it. If that's not what you want, why are you using a private method?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444576/python-method-name-with-double-underscore-is-overridden) for details. (I think there may be a question that this is even more directly a duplicate of, which is why I haven't voted to close as a dup…)

Comment: Well that definitely did the trick, taking away the dunder, but then why would that work in 2.7?

Comment: Different Kivy version maybe? If it wasn’t enumerating your class’s methods with `getattr` you would have gotten away with this, or at least that’s what it looks like in the traceback. It seems to be building some kind of proxy for your class, and that would be one way to do that, but not the only way, so maybe they used to do it differently?