# how to implement @property

Tags: python, decorator

I was comparing three slightly different implementations of `@property` in python. Python documentation and "Source 1" initialize the private variable, `_var_name`.  Furthermore, the code from Source 1 has a bug; it doesn't access `.setter` when initializing.  By contrast, the third example correctly initializes the public variable `x`.

Is there a good reason to initialize `_x` in place of `x` in `__init__`?  Are there any additional differences between these that I haven't described?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

[Source 1](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property):

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

[Source 2](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php):

```
class P:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

Comment: [The double underscore means it's a "private" name, which will be mangled so code in subclasses, etc. cannot accidentally access it; it makes no difference beyond that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444576/python-method-name-with-double-underscore-is-overridden)

Comment: The other difference is that `Celsius.temperature` is a pretty meaningful name, while `P.x`, who knows what it means, or why it's bounded to 0-1000. But I'm sure you already knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good reason to initialize `__x` or `_x` in place of `x` in `__init__`?

Properties are often used to transform the input in some way. An internal method (including `__init__`) often already *has* the transformed data, and doesn't want it to get transformed again. For example, consider this somewhat silly but obvious example:

```
class C:
    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        f = open(C.default_filename, 'rb')
        # ...
        self._file = f
    @property
    def file(self):
        return self._file.__name__
    @file.setter
    def file(self, filename):
        self._file = open(f, 'rb')
```

Even when you're not doing anything that would be *wrong* to pass through the setter, internal code often knows about the class invariants, so the checks done by setters may be extra overhead for no benefit. For example, if you wanted a method to set the temperature to 0°C, it could just set `self._x = 0` instead of `self.x = 0`, because you know that `0` doesn't need to be checked.

On the other hand, some internal methods may *want* to see `x` the same way the public does. In that case, it should use the property rather than the underlying attribute. In fact, your Source 1 is a perfect example—`__init__` just saves its parameter directly to `_temperature`, allowing you to construct temperatures below absolute 0 (which is bad, because that's actually hotter than infinity, and CPUs like to be cold). And it would be silly to repeat the same precondition test in `__init__` that you already wrote in `temperature.setter`; in this case, just set `self.temperature` instead.

---

> There is additional difference in whether a single or double underscore is used.

A single underscore makes the attribute "private by convention"; a double underscore goes further and [mangles the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444576/python-method-name-with-double-underscore-is-overridden), which means it can't be accidentally accessed from outside your class's code.

Using `obj._x` works on your instances; `obj.__x` raises `AttributeError`. But it only prevents *accidental* access—they can still use `obj._C__x` if they really want to get at it. The main reason to do this is to protect subclasses or superclasses from accidentally using the same names.

Comment: Ok. So how would you recommend fixing the problem in the example "Source 1", where `c = Celsius(-100)` does not call the `setter`?

Comment: @anon01 As I said in the answer, that is a good case where you probably do want to call the setter—just do `self.temperature = temperature`. (Although in the answer, I mixed it up and calling it `x` vs. `_x` instead of `temperature` vs. `_temperature`; I'll fix that…)